# Stopping an animation with an click event in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, sass, css-animations

I have a `MainMenuItem` that has a bunch of static titles. There is one variable item that is for news and events and that has a horizontal ticker, scroll animation on it. This animation is happening inside of the `MainMenuItem` component, but the click event will be happening from the parent. The click event currently needs to stop the animation and change the font weight (can be seen in the `readLink` class).

Wth Vue I cannot mutate the prop type itself with something like `@click="itemType = ''"`.

So how can I turn this ticker animation off on click?

Basically, all I would need to do is make the `MainMenuItem`'s `itemType = ''` and make it the same as every other item. Do I need to make a data type? Or a click event that $emit's an event to the child/base component `MainMenuItem`?

If there is anymore code that is necessary please let me know!

Cheers!

MainMenuItem.vue (base component with the ticker animation )

```
<template>
  <q-btn align="left" dense flat class="main-menu-item" v-on="$listeners">
    <div class="flex no-wrap items-center full-width">
      <iconz v-if="iconz" :name="iconz" type="pop" color="black" class="mr-md" />
      <q-icon :name="menuIcon" />
      <div v-if="itemType === 'news'" class="_ticker">
        <div class="ellipsis _ticker-item">{{ title }}</div>
      </div>
      <div v-else>
        <div class="ellipsis">{{ title }}</div>
      </div>
      <q-icon name="keyboard_arrow_right" class="_right-side" />
    </div>
  </q-btn>
</template>

<style lang="sass" scoped>
// $
.main-menu-item
  display: block
  font-size: 15px
  position: relative
  width: 100%
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F5F5F5
  +py(10px)
  ._left-side
    color: #000000

._ticker
  font-weight: bold
  margin-left: 2em
  width: 83%
  white-space: nowrap
  overflow: hidden
  position: absolute
  &-item
    display: inline-block
    padding-left: 100%
    animation: ticker 8s linear infinite

@keyframes ticker
  to
    transform: translateX(-100%)
</style>

<script>
import { iconz } from 'vue-iconz'

export default {
  name: 'MainMenuItem',
  components: { iconz },
  props: {
    comingSoonShow: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    title: { type: String, default: 'menu' },
    subtitle: { type: String, default: '' },
    menuIcon: { type: String, default: '' },
    iconz: { type: String, default: '' },
    itemType: { type: String, default: '' },
  }
}
</script>
```

MainMenu.vue (just the location I am using the base component)

```
<template>
  <MainMenuItem
   v-for="news in newsList"
   :key="news.id"
   @click="openNews(news)"
   :title="news.title"
   itemType="news"
   :class="{ readLink: readNewsList[news.id] }"
   menuIcon="contactless"
  ></MainMenuItem>
</template>

export default {
  name: 'MainMenu',
  methods: {
    openNews(postInfo) {
      dbAuthUser().merge({ seenNewsPosts: { [postInfo.id]: true } })
      Browser.open({ url: postInfo.url, presentationStyle: 'popover' })
    }
  },

  computed: {
    readNewsList() {
      return this.authUserInfo?.seenNewsPosts || {}
    },
  }

<style lang="sass" scoped>
  .readLink
    font-weight: 500
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a prop the simplest way is to emit an event that executes what you need in the parent and also bind a variable not static prop to be able to change it. example in the child :

```
<button @click="onClickButton">stop animation </button>

export default {
  methods: {
    onClickButton (event) {
      this.$emit('stopAnimation')
    }
  }
}
```

And in the parent you listen to it as so:

```
<MainMenuItem
   v-for="news in newsList"
   :key="news.id"
   @click="openNews(news)"
   :title="news.title"
   :itemType="itemType"
   :class="{ readLink: readNewsList[news.id] }"
   menuIcon="contactless"
v-on:stopAnimation="itemType = ''"
  ></MainMenuItem>

export default {
  data() {
        return {
            itemType: "news",
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! 
So emitting an event from the parent to the child component?
I tried that and my implimentation didn't really work . The parents click event 
<@click="$emit('stop-ticker')"> 
which was caught in the child with a 

<@stop-ticker="stopTicker"> 
and the method 

<stopTicker(){ this.itemType = ''}>

I'm still quite new to Vue, so this passing of data between parent and child is a bit hard for me to wrap my head around. 

I appreciate the help!

Comment: @LovelyAndy No you need to emit an event from the child to the parent isn't the button in the child? If it's in the parent you don't need any communication you can simply change it directly. If it's in the child ill edit my answer to show you how u can apply it

Comment: @LovelyAndy what you did seems correct do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: The button is in the child, correct. The parent already has a click event that opens up the news in another tab. But I figured since that click event was already there, that I should just add another click even there. 
If I make the <@click="stopTicker"> method in the child, <stopTicker(){ this.itemType = ''}> I get the error of attempting to mutate a prop.

Comment: @LovelyAndy Yes you can't put it in the child as i said you emit a parent method the way you were doing it before and as i showed in my answer do you get any errors when you try that?

Comment: Okay, so I have the child looking like this
```
 <div @click="$emit('stop-ticker')" v-if="itemType === 'news'" class="_ticker">
        <div class="ellipsis _ticker-item">{{ title }}</div>
 </div>
```

and the parent now like this: 
```
 <MainMenuItem
   v-for="news in newsList"
   :key="news.id"
   @stop-ticker="itemType = ''"
   @click="openNews(news)"
   :title="news.title"
   itemType="news"
   :class="{ readLink: readNewsList[news.id] }"
   menuIcon="contactless"
  ></MainMenuItem>
```

But this doesn't actually do anything

Comment: Sorry the code in the comments is hard to read, but I made the <@stop-ticker="itemType = ''"> in the parent and it doesn't change anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231328/discussion-between-lovelyandy-and-sibelle-khayrallah).

Comment: I sent a message in the chat, but I am getting an error: 
<Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "itemType". Expected String with value "[object Object]">